# use defaults to read desktop wallpaper change value in mac

Tags: macos

Is there a way to obtain the current setting for desktop wallpaper change either using Apple Script or defaults read? Basically I want to know by looking at the plist file if the option of changing wallpaper every X minutes is enabled or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the AppleScript dictionary for the `Desktop Suite` class of the `System Events` helper app.  It contains the property:

```
picture rotation (integer) : never, using interval, using login, after sleep
```

There are separate values for each desktop, for instance, if you have more than one monitor active.  For example:

```
tell application "System Events"
    get picture rotation of its first desktop
end tell
```